# Change href and target of an anchor

Tags: javascript, html

I've wrote this so it changes the href of the anchor with the class name but I also would like it to change the target, how do I add this?

```
window.onload = function() {
    var change = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < change.length; i++) {
        if (change[i].className.match('(^|\\s+)classnamegoeshere(\\s+|$)')) {
          change[i].href = "/urlgoeshere";
            break;
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: You should take a look at jQuery, which would make this task simple and cross browser.

Comment: @MikaelÖstberg I know jQuery and could've done this in a breeze although for this situation, I didn't see the need in including jQuery for this one thing.

Comment: Ok, your call. Maybe jQuery isn't the silver bullet one off solution to all worlds problem. I just wanted to make you aware of its existence as you appear to be a pretty new user here.

Comment: Yeah, I love jQuery, I just didn't **need** it in this instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
change[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.onload = function() {
  var change = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0, j =change.length; i < j ; i++) {
     if ((' ' + change[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + "smeCls" + ' ') > -1) {
         change[i].href = "http://www.google.com";
     }      
  }
}
```