# How to remove a href attribute from all links using php

Tags: php, html

How to remove a href attribute from all links from div element using php ?

Something like this:

```
if($condtion = "true"){
echo '<a href="" class="no-link">Please login</a>';
}
else{
echo '<a href="www.google.com" class="yes-link">Admin Section</a>';
}
```

I was searching for solution, but all what i found was solution with jquery

like this:

```
$(selector).removeAttr(attribute)
```

Thank you

Comment: What's on the `div` element?

Comment: Very similar, not really php, but may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364322/change-href-and-target-of-an-anchor

Comment: You have to use $('a').removeAttr('href'); as shown below

Comment: I need in PHP, not jquery. also when I said before, I want to remove all links from inside div element.  thank you

Comment: I do not understand your question. If you have control over how the HTML id generated, you just do what you show in your code snippet. Can you clarify the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This here checks if condition is not true then echo the link else keep the link blank. Surely something as simply is this will solve your problem.

assuming outside of a php block:

```
<a href="<?=(!$conditions ? 'www.google.com':'' ?>" class="yes-link">Admin Section</a>
```

Or in a php block:

```
echo '<a href="' . (!$conditions ? 'www.google.com':''.'" class="yes-link">Admin Section</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user  preg_replace() to achieve this. Example code:

```
$html = preg_replace('#<a class="no-link">(.*?)</a>#', '', $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

### You may use [jQuery removeAttr() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_removeattr.asp)

**Definition and Usage**

The removeAttr() method removes one or more attributes from the selected elements.

```js
$(function() {
$("a").removeAttr("href");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<a href="" > Click Me First </a><br>
<a href="" > Click Me Second </a>
</div>
```

Comment: But he also use $(selector).removeAttr(attribute) in his questtion

Answer (score 0):

```
$string1 = "<div><a href='a.php'>a</a><br><a href='b.php'>b</a><br><a href='c.php'>c</a><br><a href='d.php'>d</a></div>";
//$string2 = preg_replace("/'(.*?)'/i", '', $string1); //Uncomment this if you want empty the href value only
$string3 = preg_replace("/ href='(.*?)'/i", '', $string1); //Use this if you want to completely remove the href attribute with value
```